# What will happen if I delete a branch on my git repo and someone try to push a commit to it?

Tags: git, branch

Just a simple question that might seems dumb but I'm not a git expert!

Let's say I delete a branch in local and push my delete. The branch will no longer be on my git repository.
But what'll happen if then another user try to push a commit to this branch.

Will an error happen or will the branch be created again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't sure, so I tested it out.  It probably depends on permissions, but a new branch will be created in the target repository with the HEAD at the other user's latest commit.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your branch is still in your git repo, and the question "[Git: Recover deleted (remote) branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992364/git-recover-deleted-remote-branch)" explain how to find it back.

That also confirm [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403885/6309): pushing a branch with the same name will re-create it on the upstream remote repo side with the new history.
Since the upstream repo doesn't contain that branch (after you pushed the ref `:aBranch` to delete it), said remote repo will create a new branch with the same name.