# Git: Recover the deleted remote branch

Tags: git, github

well, I've made a very terrible mistake which first I just want to delete the remote connection to another repositories.

I've made the command like this: git push dev :test

which after I check on the github, I'm just realize that the branch test already deleted.

Question: how can I get the branch back? Is it possible to undo the command which I've already made?

Comment: do you still have this branch somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Recover deleted (remote) branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992364/git-recover-deleted-remote-branch)

Comment: I have the branch on my repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you still have the local copy with you? Run `git branch` to check, you probably still have your local branch there since you don't mention removing the local branch.

If this is this case, just push to the remote repository again, with `git push dev test` without the colon.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the branch on my repositories.

If you haven’t removed it in your local repository yet, you can just push it again to recreate it.

```
git push dev localbranch:test
```

Or if you don’t have the branch itself, but still remember which commit was on top, you can also just push that commit directly:

```
git push dev some-commit-hash:test
```

Answer (score -1):

that's not possible to recover after a remote branch is deleted.

since git is DVCS, you'd pray that others didn't get their local copy updated,
let them help *forth* push your `test` branch into remote.
that's the only way to get your branch back, I guess.

since you're in github, maybe there're some forks available? that's also an alternative.

Comment: ignore this answer if you didn't get your local repo erased.