# Is there a way or github api to check exactly WHEN a hard reset was performed on a given branch

Tags: github, github-api

We are performing the following

```sh
    git checkout copy_from_branch
    git checkout branch_getting_changed
    git reset --hard origin/copy_from_branch
```

Now, `branch_getting_changed` becomes exact copy of `copy_from_branch` in terms of commits.

Since they are exact copies, we are not able to check the `TIMESTAMP` of exactly when the reset action was performed on the `branch_getting_changed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the reset is executed locally, in your local git repository, you can then refer to [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

```
git reflog --date=iso
```

You will see the reset entry, and its associated date.

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer. This will work on local. However this event should also be logged on remote if someone else wants to check when reset was executed. Like if we could get similar result using github API or if someone else checks out the branch again on different machine and then runs this command.

Comment: @codeaprendiz That depends on the remote Git repositories hosting service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343686/6309 records a force push on PR branch. For the rest, check the push events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309

Comment: @codeaprendiz You are welcome. Also of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28885864/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030429/6309.