# How to undelete a branch on github?

Tags: git, github

It seems that I delete a branch on github when I should not do it.

What I did was as follow:

1- I add a new .gitignore to my system

2- I use

```
 git rm -r --cached .  
 git add .  
 git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

When I did this, I had one branch on my local system but the server had two branch.

Then I pushed my branches to server and since I had not the second branch, the second branch was deleted on server.

How can I bring it back?

I am using Github as remote server.

Comment: how did you pushed your branches?

Comment: @juanpastas: I am using git from inside VS and I used git > push > push multiple branches and I select the branch that I had not on my local repository

Comment: *push. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992364/git-recover-deleted-remote-branch

Comment: checkout this link http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2012/07/05/undelete-a-branch-in-git/

Comment: FYI if you delete a branch on GitHub's web UI, you can easily restore it: https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/#deleting-branches

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you know the last commit message of the deleted branch you can do this:

```
git reflog
```

# search for message

```
fd0e4da HEAD@{14}: commit: This is the commit message I want
```

# checkout revision

```
git checkout fd0e4da
```

or

```
git checkout HEAD@{14}
```

# create branch

```
git branch my-recovered-branch
```

# push branch

```
git push origin my-recovered-branch:my-recovered-branch
```

Comment: But if you don't know that commit message?

Comment: To make searching git reflog a little easier: git reflog | grep 'This is the commit message I want'

Comment: This leaves you in a "detached HEAD" state.

Comment: Doing another

    `git checkout my-recovered-branch`

cleared the detached HEAD.

Comment: `git checkout fd0e4da` might not work if that SHA isn't local. What works is to insert the name of the remote so that it looks there, e.g.: `git checkout origin fd0e4da`, that saved me.

Answer (score 19):

If this branch was deleted during the Pull Request, you can undo that right there in the UI using the "restore branch" button.

Tricky part is actually finding a PR that has been merged and closed, you just need to know the URL or the PR number to put into the URL. You can try looking in your deleted notification emails or just guess the PR number.

Writing this cause `reflog` didn't help me restoring a teammate commit to a branch I've never pulled on my local git.

Comment: that saved me a lot of grief! :)

Answer (score 4):

what if you `git fetch remote && git checkout -b remote_branch_name`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work: $ git fetch remote
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: `remote` is the name of your remote repo (GitHub in this case). try `git remote list` to see the name of your remote repo (I think that is `origin`) and use that name instead of `remote`

Answer (score 0):

Inside github.com you can restore it after the fact by Pull requests, open the last request and you should see a Recover/Restore branch button