# How do I manage changes to my db across git branches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, migration

So, I have an app that I am experimenting with.

The current state is good on my `develop` branch. I want to install spree, but that comes with many migrations and changes to the db.

So I made a new branch, just for Spree, based on my `develop` branch.

I installed the gem, ran the migrations, and all that stuff.

However, I messed up a few stuff, so I wanted to revert to my `develop` branch and deleted the `spree` branch.

I assumed that my `schema.rb` would return to normal and so would my DB.

But then I look in my `Schema.rb` and I see a lot of Spree tables.

Not only that, but I also see other tables in my `Schema.rb` that I know I had created a migration for and 'dropped' in the `spree` branch.

So, for instance, I have an `orders` table in my `Schema.rb` that I know should have been dropped. A bit confused, I decide to create a new migration to drop the `orders` table along with the other tables that I dropped before installing spree and I get a PG error saying that the table doesn't exist.

So....it seems that right now, my schema.rb and DB don't sync up.

And to make matters worse, my schema.rb and my `db/migrate` folder doesn't sync up.

I was going to manually delete the `create_table` statements in my schema.rb for the tables that shouldn't be there - but then it's all a mess.

How do I dig myself out of this hole and how do I prevent it in the future?

### **In Summary**

**DB**

Pre-Spree State

- Table A
- Table B
- Table C

Spree State

- Table A (removed)
- Table B (removed)
- Table C
- Spree_Table_A
- Spree_Table_B

Post-Spree State

- Table A (removed)
- Table B (removed)
- Table C
- Spree_Table_A
- Spree_Table_B

*Basically identical to the **Spree State***

**DB/Migrate Folder**

Pre-Spree State

- Migration for Table A
- Migration for Table B
- Migration for Table C

Spree State

- Migration to Remove Table A
- Migration to Remove Table B
- Migration for Table C
- Migration for Spree_Table_A
- Migration for Spree_Table_B

Post-Spree State

- Migration for Table A
- Migration for Table B
- Migration for Table C

*Note that the migrations for the 'Post-Spree State' don't sync up with the state of the DB of the 'Post-Spree State'.*

Comment: Did both of your branches use the same database? (spree branch should have had its own database). Did you `down` the migrates before deleting them? The schema file in your develop branch shouldn't have been affected by migrates in another branch running on another database.

Comment: Both branches do share the same db - didn't think of having 2 separate dbs for branches. not sure how feasible that is. I didn't `down` the migrations before deleting - silly me. I thought the `up` migrations were contained to that 1 branch - so it didn't even occur to me to be honest.

Comment: It's safer to have a separate db for other branches, even if it's just a snapshot of the development db. You will need to restore the migrates (if possible) and run the down on them to get your database back to where you had it.

Comment: How can I do that if the branch was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Converted comments to answer since it was getting quite lengthy:

It's safer to have a separate database for any new branch, even if it's just a snapshot of the development database. You will need to restore the migrates (if possible) from your spree branch and run the down on them to get your database back to where you had it.

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=xxx
```

Where `xxx` is equal to the number of the last migrate before spree

I'm not a git expert, but if your branch was deleted through git then this thread may help you restore it. If you only deleted it locally then you should be able to just check it out again.

[Git: Recover deleted (remote) branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992364/git-recover-deleted-remote-branch)

Answer (score 1):

When you switch back to your `develop` branch, git should check out your original `schema.rb` (if this isn't happening, I think you should recheck the git command you're using).  However, it **won't** automatically bring your DB back into line with where it was when you created `spree`.

If you no longer have the required migration files to get your DB state back to one that corresponds to the commit you're checking out of git, you should use `rake db:reset` to get them to match up.  This will dump the current state of the DB and rebuild it using `schema.rb` (then apply the appropriate seed file).

Comment: This is the best answer. Generally don't worry about schema.rb file, it's really only used by tests (well, ok it has some other uses, but you don't need to spend a lot of time with it). Another strategy is to start from scratch (drop the table), run db:migrate from the beginning of time, and then just check-in whatever you have in schema.rb. One thing you may not realize is that db/schema.rb is re-written from what's currently in your DB EVERY time you run db:migrate, even if the migration didn't make those changes. People new to Rails often confuse this.