# Can we get git recent deleted repository back?

Tags: git

I am using Git Tower a git GUI , by mistake i have deleted the repository from GUI this also delete from my local , so there any way to get back the deleted repository ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I recover branch after its deletion in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Comment: If the deleted repo has some new commits that have not been updated to another repo, I'm afraid you need a disk recovery tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you just deleted from local, but exist in remote you can simply checkout from remote

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

if you delete from local & remote, than you can do it from commit `sha`

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> <sha>
```

Many thread exist already for this 
[SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640806/1225337), 
[SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992364/git-recover-deleted-remote-branch)

Comment: This is about to get the branch , but i also lost all the files so this is not a git directory right now, i can't run command over their .

Comment: did you start from `bare` git repository?